# Running NUnit tests multiple times

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, ncrunch

I have a suite of NUnit tests, some of which fail intermittently, probably because of timing problems. I'd like to find these flaky unit tests. Is there a way to repeat each test multiple times without having to put a Repeat() attribute on each test? We routinely use the resharper and ncrunch runners, but also have access to the nunit gui and console runners.

Comment: You may be doing too much in each unit test - they should only contain a single test for one single part of your system. Are you able to add the code for the suspect unit test to your question?

Comment: Hi Piers. I'm happy that the tests are not overly complicated. More that, the tests inherently have a timing dependency built in (using  DateTime calculations, and timers etc). They pass most of the time, and fail unpredictably and sporadically.

Answer (score 3):

## NUnit 3

In NUnit 3, you may use [**Retry**](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Retry-Attribute) attribute:

> `RetryAttribute` is used on a test method to specify that it should be
>   rerun if it fails, up to a maximum number of times.
>
> Notes:
>
> It is not currently possible to use `RetryAttribute` on a `TestFixture` or any other type of test suite. Only single tests may be
>   repeated.
>
> If a test has an unexpected exception, an error result is returned and it is not retried. Only assertion failures can trigger a retry. To
>   convert an unexpected exception into an assertion failure, see the
>   `ThrowsConstraint`.

## NUnit 2

NUnit 2 doesn't support retries, but you may use **NUnit-retry** plug-in ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit-retry/), [GitHub](https://github.com/slvnperron/NUnit-retry)). An example of use:

```
private static int run = 0;

...

[Test]
[Retry(Times = 3, RequiredPassCount = 2)]
public void One_Failure_On_Three_Should_Pass()
{
    run++;

    if (run == 1)
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

    Assert.Pass();
}
```

## See also

- [Feature - Add 'Retry Attribute' to repeat test upon failure](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/1039415). Discussion about the feature on Launchpad

Comment: @Daruisz I have over 6000 unit tests. Is there a centralized way of running all the tests multiple times?

Comment: @PhillipNgan: NUnit-retry allows to put Retry attribute on either class or method, so the answer is – it's not possible to do that by using this tool.

Comment: But if it can be applied to a class then that *is* better than the standard NUnit, which only allows [Repeat] at test method level.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work (couldn't figure out the installation instructions!)